# double free or corruption (out) C++

Tags: c++, class, memory, constructor, runtime-error

I know a double free or corruption error is usually a violation of the big 3, but in this instance, I cannot find where the violation occurs. I have a copy constructor, destructor, and assignment operator for anything that deals with pointers.

In my .h here is my class implementation:

```
class BST
{
public:
    struct SequenceMap{
        std::string astring;
        std::vector<std::string> sequences;

        //void setValue(std::string theString, std::string anotherString);
        SequenceMap& operator=(const SequenceMap map);

        void setValue(std::string theString, std::string anotherString);

        SequenceMap(); //constructor no copy since no pointers
        ~SequenceMap();
    };
    struct BinaryNode{
        SequenceMap item;
        BinaryNode *left;
        BinaryNode *right;
        BinaryNode(SequenceMap i); //constructor

        inline bool operator> (std::string t);
        inline bool operator< (std::string t);

        BinaryNode& operator=(const BinaryNode node) ;
        ~BinaryNode();
        BinaryNode(const BinaryNode &otherNode);
    };
    BinaryNode *root;
    int insert(SequenceMap &x, BinaryNode *&t, bool &ifdup);

    BST();
    ~BST();
    void BSTClear(BST::BinaryNode *t);
    BST(const BST &otherTree);

    BST& operator=(const BST tree);
};
```

I implemented my constructors, destructors and assignment operators in my .cpp:

```
BST::SequenceMap& BST::SequenceMap::operator=(const BST::SequenceMap map) 
{
    astring = map.astring;
    sequences = map.sequences;
    return *this;
}

inline bool BST::BinaryNode::operator<(std::string t){//does compare}
inline bool BST::BinaryNode::operator>(std::string t){//does compare}

BST::BinaryNode& BST::BinaryNode::operator=(const BST::BinaryNode node) 
{
    item = node.item;
    if(node.left != nullptr)
        left = new BST::BinaryNode(node.left->item);
    else
        left = nullptr;
    if(node.right != nullptr)
        right = new BST::BinaryNode(node.right->item);
    else
        right = nullptr;

    return *this;
}
BST& BST::operator=(const BST tree){root = new BinaryNode(tree.root);}

BST::BinaryNode::BinaryNode(const BST::BinaryNode &otherNode){
    item = otherNode.item;  
    if(otherNode.left != nullptr)
        left = new BST::BinaryNode(otherNode.left->item);
    else
        left = nullptr;
    if(otherNode.right != nullptr)
        right = new BST::BinaryNode(otherNode.right->item);
    else
        right = nullptr;
}

BST::BinaryNode::BinaryNode(SequenceMap i){ item = i; left = nullptr; right = nullptr; }
BST::BinaryNode::~BinaryNode(){ delete &item; left = nullptr; right = nullptr; }

BST::BST(){root = nullptr;}
BST::BST(const BST &otherTree){root = new BinaryNode(otherTree.root->item);}
BST::~BST(){BSTClear(root);}

BST::SequenceMap::SequenceMap(){astring = "";}
BST::SequenceMap::~SequenceMap(){ delete &astring; delete &sequences;}

void BST::BSTClear(BST::BinaryNode*t){
    if(t->left != nullptr)
        BSTClear(t->left);
    if(t->right != nullptr)
        BSTClear(t->right);      
    delete t;
}
```

I used `cout` to test for where the error occurs and it occurs when I do this in my main.cpp on the indicated line:

```
while(getline(sequences,sequence) && getline(enzymes,enzyme))
{
    BST::SequenceMap map = BST::SequenceMap;
    map->setValue(sequence, enzyme);

    sequenceTree->insert(map, sequenceTree->root, dup); //ON THIS LINE
}
```

and in my insert function in my .cpp:

```
int BST::insert(BST::SequenceMap &x, BST::BinaryNode *&t, bool &ifdup )
{
    if(t == nullptr)
    {
        //std::cout<<"2"<<std::endl;            
        t = new BST::BinaryNode(x); //ON THIS LINE  
        //std::cout<<"1"<<std::endl;
    }
    //do more things
 }
```

I'm not sure if this is considered MSCV, but I this is the least I need to reproduce my error.
[image: Stack Trace]

Comment: Use valgrind or a debugger to pinpoint the problem.  At a minimum you should be able to include a stack trace in your question.

Comment: @JohnZwinck is there one that is windows compatible as well as c++11 compatible? I don't have access to a linux machine atm

Comment: You haven't included the BinaryNode constructor.

Comment: @DominicMcDonnell `BST::BinaryNode::BinaryNode(SequenceMap i){ item = i; left = nullptr; right = nullptr; }` right under my copy constructor.

Comment: @SemicolonExpected: there are a number of debuggers on Windows as I'm sure you're aware.  I'm not sure about valgrind, but even a regular debugger can tell you where you're crashing.

Comment: Ah, you hadn't added them yet when I viewed the question.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have included a stack trace

Comment: In your destructor for `BinaryNode` you have `delete &item;`. The value `&item` is not an allocated pointer, so you should remove the delete statement. However, you should be deleting `left` and `right` as they are allocated pointers.

Comment: @TheDark yup and same with my destructor for SequenceMaps, I also found that my contains didn't check for null properly, and that fixed everything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider your `BinaryNode` assignment operator.

```
BST::BinaryNode& BST::BinaryNode::operator=(const BST::BinaryNode node) 
{
    item = node.item;
    if(node.left != nullptr)
        left = node.left;
    else
        left = nullptr;
    if(node.right != nullptr)
        right = node.right;
    else
        right = nullptr;

    return *this;
}
```

You still end up with both instances of the `BinaryNode` having their `left` and `right` pointers pointing to the same thing. When the destructors of the two instances are called, they will both free up the pointers and cause a double free.

What you need to do is to actually make a new copy the *values* pointed to by the `left` and `right` pointers, not the *pointers*, or have some sort of reference counted pointer.

Also note: Your if tests don't add any value as you are just assigning `nullptr` if the original value is `nullptr`

Comment: How would I deep copy this? Would it have to be something like `left = new BST::BinaryNode(left->item)` and that will recursively create a new "subtree" identical to the first or will that not work?

Comment: Yes, that is right. All your copy constructor would need to do would be to recursively call itself for the `left` and `right` nodes, if they are not `nullptr`. Fortunately, you already have the if tests that you need :)

Comment: Actually you want `left = BST::BinaryNode(node.left)`, so you invoke the copy constructor.